# Composition of permutations in factoradic notation

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, number-systems

The [Lehmer code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_code) maps between permutations and natural numbers.  My question: Is a "nice" algorithm known for composing permutations directly in the factoradic form?

When the permutations commute, it looks like digits can be added in modular fashion.  For example, $$1\,1\,1\,0_{!} \cdot 2\,1\,0\,0_{!} =3\,2\,1\,0_!.$$

But when they don't, something more is wanted.

Comment: Your rule for commuting permutations cannot hold in general (for example, try muliplying the permutation $k\mapsto n+1-k $ with itself), though it would be interesting to describe cases in which works (particularly, where there is no "carry").